# FOL application expression

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm attempting to implement (using NLTK's logic module) the translation of Abstract Meaning Representation (AMR) to First-Order Logic described here (http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/COLI_a_00257), but I think there are some gaps in how the paper describes the procedure.

In one of the examples, it shows that when

```
λp.∃x(person(x)∧named(x,”Mr Krupp”)∧p)
```

is applied to

```
∃e(dry(e)∧ARG0(e,x)∧ARG1(e,x))
```

you get

```
∃x(person(x)∧named(x,”Mr Krupp”)∧∃e(dry(e)∧ARG0(e,x)∧ARG1(e,x))).
```

However, when I attempt to do this, I get

```
∃z1.(person(z1) & named(z1,"Mr_SPACE_Krupp") & ∃e.(dry(e) & ARG0(e,x) & ARG1(e,x)))
```

and $x$ remains a free variable.

I also tried replacing the second expression with

```
λx.∃e(dry(e)∧ARG0(e,x)∧ARG1(e,x))
```

but that does not work (the result is ∃z1(person(z1) & named(z1,"Mr_SPACE_Krupp") & λx.∃e(dry(e) & ARG0(e,x) & ARG1(e,x))).

I'm assuming there's something missing from the second expression to obtain the right result. Is that right? If so, what should that expression be?

Also, I know very little about FOL and if someone has a reference to a good introduction that will help me figure out this sorts of gaps in the paper, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [Lambda calculus : free and bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Free_and_bound_variables) : "The set of free variables of a lambda expression $M$ is denoted as $FV(M)$ and $FV(λx.M) = FV(M) \setminus \{ x \}$".

Comment: Thus, in your $λp.∃x( \ldots ∧ p)$ we have that $FV(λp.M) = FV(M) \setminus \{ p \}$. But in $M$ (i.e. in $∃x( \ldots ∧ p)$) $x$ is quantified; thus $x \notin FV(M)$.

Comment: The issue is that you are applying the function $λp.∃x(…∧p)$ (a function of $p$) to an object that has $x$ free. If you do this, the $x$ free in the second expression will be "captured" by the quantifier $∃x$ of the first one, and this is not what we want. Thus, the "trick" is to rename the bound var in the first expression getting the equivalent $λp.∃z(…∧p)$ and then applying it to the second expression. In this way, the $x$ will stay free also in the resulting expression.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I want the $x$ free in the second expression to be captured by the quantified $\exists x$ from the first one, but it's not working. If could be a problem with my code and not the logic itself?

Comment: I do not understand... the code is written by you or it is a "commercial" one ? If the second, I assume, it has been designed to make correct substitution: thus, the prior renaming of bound var in order to avoiding "capturing"...

Comment: If instead it is your creation... I think that you can do what you want.